# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method with [class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver]

Tags: java, appium

Im trying run my TestNG test and I am getting this error:

```
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [Test1] with [class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver].
```

Dont know what must do. I'm using Appium whit TestNG.

```
@Listeners(ExtentITestListenerAdapter.class)
public class TestNG {

    public AppiumDriver <AndroidElement>driver;

    @Test
    public void Test1(AndroidDriver driver) {
        MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("skip_button");
        el1.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(725, 993)).perform();
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(293, 1005)).perform();
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(1175, 1531)).perform();
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(1166, 2029)).perform();
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(763, 2036)).perform();
        MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("continue_button");
        el2.click();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel_4_2");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\Diego\\Desktop\\flow-music-develop-dev-debug-v0.11.0-SNAPSHOT-209.apk");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("ensureWebviewsHavePages", true);

        URL remoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the method `[coordsWizardFuncionando2]`? Are you sure you provide this class that produces the error?

Comment: Yes, this is the method, i forget change the name here, but this is the method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parameters in test method, you need to provide the DataProvider or using Parameter from file `testng.xml`

Link to docs: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

In this case, just remove the parameter of method, i.e `public void Test1(AndroidDriver driver)` -> `public void Test1()`

Comment: If i remove the parameter and use public void Test1() i get this error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(String)" because "this.driver" is null

Comment: Did you actually try to remove it? or you just thought `driver` will be null. You've already instantiated the `driver` in `@BeforeClass`  `driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);` ---> `driver` can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception{

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel_4_2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\Diego\\Desktop\\flow-music-develop-dev-debug-v0.11.0-SNAPSHOT-209.apk");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("ensureWebviewsHavePages", true);



    URL remoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);
    String sessionId = driver.getSessionId().toString();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
```

I declare this method using the @BeforeMethod, if you seed this method contain this
"driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);"
Using this i havent the problem.
Ty all